# query substring two ways

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have a query like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE col1 LIKE '%fox jumped over%' "
```

This will find a result if `col1` has a value of `the fox jumped over the dog`. How Could I modify this query so it would also find a match for "jumped over".

I need a query that checks for `LIKE` both ways, if that makes sense.

I  do not know the value of col1, therefore I can not have a condition like `"%jumped over%"`. I can only work with the value parsed.

I'm currently building the query and then parsing it into a custom pdo function.

Comment: just `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE col1 LIKE '%jumped over%' `

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE col1 LIKE '%fox jumped over%'  OR col1 LIKE '%jumped over%'`

Comment: "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE col1 LIKE '%fox jumped over%' OR col1 LIKE '%jumped over%' "

Comment: Why is everybody trying to use 2 conditions in their suggestions? If you do a wildcard search for `%jumped over%` you do not need to also check for `%fox jumped over%`. First one will match second one too

Comment: @HankyPanky Yes! True That!

Comment: These suggestion assume I know the value of col1.

Comment: Can you share the php query build code you have so far.

Comment: Incidentally, the phrase is 'jumps over'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a lot of people have misunderstood what you need. If I understand you correctly you need the following query:

```
   SELECT * FROM Table1 
    WHERE col1 LIKE '%fox jumped over%' OR 'fox jumped over' LIKE CONCAT('%', col1, '%')
```

Comment: Genius! - thanks a lot. I didn't know you could reverse the comparison like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output by using below query -

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE col1 LIKE '%fox jumped over%'" OR 
col1 LIKE '%jumped over%'
```

Comment: There is no need for the first condition then

Comment: This isn't very pragmatic. This assumes I know the value of col1

Comment: It is also required because you want to result which have either **fox jumped over** or **jumped over**

Comment: when you are matching `%jumped over%` then it can match a fox/dog/cat/lion/whatever jumped over. Even if nothing jumped over it will match

Comment: It was an example. It could also have been `fox jumped` that I need matching. That's what I mean by two way matching. Otherwise I would just have a like of `LIKE '%jumped over%'`. that's basic sql. This is a complex problem - I have a word that needs resolving both ways without knowing the value of col1 in every record.

Comment: Can you share the table with records sothat it can be resolved easily